# I'm stock with a SQL statement, about getting the right amount

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am so sorry if there is already an answer for this question, I just haven't been able to find it.

I am making a little chart to my home systems, which is a overview of my savings, I already have a chart showing how much is going in each months.

This is the SQL statement I have managed to get working so far

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total, DATE(dt) AS `date` FROM `savings` GROUP BY MONTH(`date`)
```

Which gives this result:
[SQL result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f001.png)

But this is not fully what I am doing to get, since this statement gives an amount for each month, what I need is one that add to the last amount, so that I can see the full amount of saving over months, if that makes sense?

Comment: Before you go any further, you should fix your sql. It will fail in any database except for pre-5.7 mysql (or post-5.7 mysql with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` set to the non-default value of False). Where this is going to cause in issue in the future is 1). In a year or two from now you will have more than one year that yields the same `month(date)` but your sql will only spit out one of the dates that match that (this years date or next years... it will be random and nonsense). 2) If you move to a newer version of mysql or any other RDBMS, this sql will error.

Comment: So instead: `SELECT sum(amount) as total, Month(Date(dt)) as monthdt, Year(Date(dt)) as yeardt FROM savings GROUP BY monthdt, yeardt;`. That doesn't answer your question though. To answer your question, can you please share wha version of mysql you are on. Window functions are the likely route to solving, but those aren't available in older versions.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that issue, not a problem tho, since I will only show current year, but it is on my list to take care off.

Comment: Servertype: MariaDB
Serverversion: 10.3.34-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 - Raspbian 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total, EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM dt) AS `yearmonth` 
FROM `savings` 
GROUP BY yearmonth WITH ROLLUP;
```

This does your grouping by year/month, plus adds one more row to the result set, with the total. The yearmonth column will be returned as NULL on that rollup row.

Comment: Thanks mate, didn't knew of the WITH ROLLUP function, it ain't always easy searching for stuff when you don't know what to search for :) But, I just tried it and my MySQL (MariaDB) says that WITH and ROLLUP is unknown keywords, is there anything I need to do for WITH ROLLUP to work?

Comment: Wait, it's working, just forgot to select the correct database, doh :) Thank you so much!

Comment: In this case, the ROLLUP option should work the same in MySQL and MariaDB, because it has been in the code since before MariaDB forked in 2010. But in general, if you use MariaDB you should not assume it's compatible with MySQL. Since 2010, both products have added many features independently, so they are effectively different products now.

Comment: Yeah; I always read up on things if needed, since as you say, can't expect it to be the same. But it is working now, just forgot to select database, thanks!